# Constructing a loop in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm writing an Ansible role that sets up the network. For each type of interface (ethernet, bond, bridge and vlan) I made a variable that contains the relevant data.
The idea is that I have to make a loop that runs the number of times that there are elements in a list variable ('bridge_ports') and for each pass a configuration file is created via a template.

Parts of the variable for bridge interfaces look like this:

```
my_network__bridge_interface:
    address: "192.168.1.48",
    bootproto: "static",
    bridge_ports:
        - eth0
        - eth1
    device: "br-mgmt",
    ...
```

To make the pass, I have tried with a with_subelements loop - but this does not go well.

```
- name: Create the network configuration file for the port on the bridge devices
  template:
    src: "{{ ansible_os_family }}.bridge_port.j2"
    dest: "{{ my_network__ifconf_path }}/ifcfg-{{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements
    - "{{ my_network__bridge_interface }}"
    - bridge_ports
  when: device_conf.type == 'bridge'
  register: my_network__bridge_port_result
```

When I run the code, the error message comes: "could not find 'bridge_ports' key in iterated item '{}'".

I can see that I use with_subelements in the wrong way, but I don't really know what type of loop I would otherwise need.

Comment: FWIW. See [netplan.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/netplan.yml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the yml definition. The below yml works:

```
my_network__bridge_interface:

  - address: "192.168.1.48"
    bootproto: static
    bridge_ports:
      - eth0
      - eth1
    device: br-mgmt
```

playbook -->

```
    ---
    - hosts: localhost
      tasks:
        - include_vars: vars.yml
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
          with_subelements:
            - "{{ my_network__bridge_interface }}"
            - bridge_ports
```

output -->

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'device': u'br-mgmt', u'bootproto': u'static', u'address': u'192.168.1.48'}, u'eth0']) => {
    "msg": "eth0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'device': u'br-mgmt', u'bootproto': u'static', u'address': u'192.168.1.48'}, u'eth1']) => {
    "msg": "eth1"
}
```